# MS Access - wildcard join versus filtering with no join

Tags: sql, database, performance, ms-access, ms-access-2013

the way I see it I have two options for "joining" two tables using wildcards on the joining fields. I and wondering from a performance perspective which is more efficient?

option 1 -- wild card join

```
select *
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.field like "*" + table2.field
```

option 2 -- not sure what this is called

```
select *
from table1, table2
where table1.field like "*" + table2.field
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both the same.  You basically have to do a nested loop join for this type of wildcard condition.  A nested loop join does the cartesian product and filters the results.

However, I prefer the first option, because being explicit about what is being joined usually makes queries easier to read, understand, and maintain.